# change DetailsView Mode from Readonly to Edit from code behind

Tags: vb.net, detailsview

I am facing problem to change the details view mode from `ReadOnly` to `Edit`. `Readonly` is the default mode but I want that when first time my details view will call then it's mode will be `Readonly` and then I change it into `Edit` mode from codebehind.

```
DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit)
```

That is the way I change mode to `Edit` from `ReadOnly`, but that does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Read only mode is the default mode of detailsview.To go to edit mode just add

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
```

after `<fields>`